# How do I exclude the following code using conditional preprocessor

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

For e.g.

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    { 
        unsigned fb_num                :  8 __attribute__ ((packed));
        unsigned stream_id             : 12 __attribute__ ((packed));
        unsigned lossless              :  1 __attribute__ ((packed));
        unsigned proto_idx             :  6 __attribute__ ((packed));
        unsigned da_logport            : 13 __attribute__ ((packed));
        unsigned sa_spare_dx           : 10 __attribute__ ((packed));
        unsigned da_spare_idx          : 10 __attribute__ ((packed));
        unsigned mcast_index           : 12 __attribute__ ((packed));/* ISH_B*/
        unsigned mesh_idx              :  8 __attribute__ ((packed));
        unsigned in_mirror             :  4 __attribute__ ((packed));
        unsigned vlan_idx              : 12 __attribute__ ((packed));
        unsigned dis_stp               :  1 __attribute__ ((packed));
        unsigned trkbal_idx            :  5 __attribute__ ((packed));
...
```

I want to exclude this code portion: `__attribute__ ((packed))`, so that compiler reads it as:

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    { 
        unsigned fb_num                :  8 ;
        unsigned stream_id             : 12 ;
        unsigned lossless              :  1 ;
        unsigned proto_idx             :  6 ;
        unsigned da_logport            : 13 ;
        unsigned sa_spare_dx           : 10 ;
        unsigned da_spare_idx          : 10 ;
        unsigned mcast_index           : 12 ;/* ISH_B*/
        unsigned mesh_idx              :  8 ;
        unsigned in_mirror             :  4 ;
        unsigned vlan_idx              : 12 ;
        unsigned dis_stp               :  1 ;
        unsigned trkbal_idx            :  5 ;
...
```

Now the MACRO under which this should compile is `MCAST_SIMULATION`:
i.e. if `MCAST_SIMULATION` is defined, exclude the mentioned code portion otherwise not.
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You define `__attribute__()` to nothing.

Like this:

```
#ifdef MCAST_SIMULATION
# define __attribute__(x)
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks @Joachim Pileborg. But compiling the code now produces huge number of these warnings:
Warning 3 warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro '__attribute__' 

Is there any way to suppress this?

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce your own macro for this. Something like:

```
#ifndef MCAST_SIMULATION
#define ATTRIB_PACKED __attribute__((packed))
#else
#define ATTRIB_PACKED
#endif
```

Usage:

```
unsigned fb_num :  8 ATTRIB_PACKED ;
```

Comment: Ok I guess this seems to be most optimal fix. Thanks a lot @jrok!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the text `__attribute__ ((packed))` with a macro (e.g.
`PACKED`, and conditionally define that:

```
#ifndef MCAST_SIMULATION
#define PACKED __attribute__ ((packed))
#else
#define PACKED
#endif
```